# "Catalog Search indexer process unknown error: null" with Elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, magento2.3.3, elasticsearch

> After enabling Elasticsearch6+ as Catalog Search engine in Magento
>   admin (M2.3.3) I'm receiving this error while reindexing:
>
> Catalog Search indexer process unknown error: null

Answer (score 3):

> This was caused by the fact that I had not set a prefix for
>   Elasticsearch in the magento admin configurations.
>
> After setting magento2 as the value for the prefix the indexing
>   started working.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

and then run

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/elasticsearch.conf

=> paste this code

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2ensite elasticsearch.conf
```

[Visit this link for detailed clarification](https://www.magetop.com/blog/install-magento-2-4-2-on-ubuntu/#5_Install_Elasticsearch)